# resizable is adding second wrapper instead of changing the size of first one

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-resizable

I am using resizable() and draggable() jquery UI functions for manipulating the pictures in my app.

The code works fine:

```
  $(document).on('click', 'img', function(event){ 
         $(this).resizable(); 
         $(".ui-wrapper").draggable();

    return false;
   });
```

The problem is, that, when I am coming back to "content-editor" mode of my application it works wrong, because resizable() is adding second ".ui-wrapper" instead of manipulating the old one.

[You can see the problem on my application](http://impress-builder.herokuapp.com/home) - go to content mode, add picture, resize it, get back to style mode, than back again to content mode - and here, when you click on the picture the resizable and draggable is not working correctly. the effect is like that: http://jsfiddle.net/7GrbM/6/

Answer (score 0):

your approach will create lots of trouble, me i'd put a button drag/resize on the image & if clicked then first destroy resizable/draggable instances then resizable/draggable of  that image; a bit more work for the user for less surprises

then change of mode -> reset all to not draggable/not resizable

or i'd put all img resizable/draggable by default (and destroy upon saving/exporting/whatever

also why not ?

```
 $(document).on('click', 'img', function(event){ 

     $(this).resizable().draggable();

return false;
});
```

Comment: $(this).resizable().draggable(); - is not working properly for me, i don't know why. i can drag the picture only within the area if set resizable()